# Centering a content in all devices using padding-top

Tags: css, viewport, centering, responsive

I have been having trouble centering the `.content` div in any device. In some devices, the `.content` is exactly centered but not in others. I use `padding-top` to push the `.content` down so it could be placed on the center of any device. What should I do to center the `.content` in any device using `padding-top`? Should I use Javascript in this kind of situation?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.whole {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #d44949;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  font: 1.4em 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.logo > span {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #d8d8d8;
}

.header-nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
}

.header-nav > a {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 1em 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.header-nav > a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.header-nav > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: calc(100vh / 2);
}

.content > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.content-nav {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.content-nav > a {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 1em 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.content-nav > a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo">Max<span>&</span>Spoon</h1>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <a href="/">Download</a>
      <a href="/">Docs</a>
      <a href="/">Tutorial</a>
      <a href="/">Reference</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://emblemsbf.com/img/36593.jpg" alt="logo">
    <div class="content-nav">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="/">Blog</a>
      <a href="/">Forum</a>
      <a href="/">Stuff</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use padding? Can you use flex? Am I right in thinking you want the object to be vertically centered on all devices?

Comment: Yes. Is there any better solution than padding?

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `flex` you could remove the `padding-top` and add `align-items: center;` to your `.content`.

So your CSS for `.content` becomes:

```
.content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

Here's the updated snippet.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.whole {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #d44949;
}
header:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.logo {
  font: 1.4em'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.logo > span {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #d8d8d8;
}
.header-nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
}
.header-nav > a {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 1em'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.header-nav > a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.header-nav > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.content > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
.content-nav {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.content-nav > a {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 1em'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.content-nav > a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo">Max<span>&</span>Spoon</h1>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <a href="/">Download</a>
      <a href="/">Docs</a>
      <a href="/">Tutorial</a>
      <a href="/">Reference</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://emblemsbf.com/img/36593.jpg" alt="logo">
    <div class="content-nav">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="/">Blog</a>
      <a href="/">Forum</a>
      <a href="/">Stuff</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried other devices; the `.content` still remained placed on the top